# Query para fazer levantamento de nomes que iniciam com espaço em branco

Tags: sql, oracle, dbeaver

Estou fazendo um levantamento para minha empresa e precisava de ajuda para fazer uma query na qual retorne pra mim todos os nomes de clientes que tenham espaço antes do nome.

Por exemplo:

```
" Nildo oliveira santos" 
" Carlos oliveira santos"
" Paula oliveira santos"
" Jady oliveira santos"
```

Comment: afinal qual é o banco de dados? tem tags de mysql, oracle....

Comment: já tentou `LIKE ' %'`?

Comment: Já tentei com LIKE mas sem sucesso!

Comment: Acho que a forma mais certa seria com substring porém não estou conseguindo fazer com isso.

Comment: se algo começa com espaço esse like ia pegar tem algo a mais ai

Comment: realmente @RicardoPontual eu executei a sua versão do comando e produz os mesmos resultados (pelo menos utilizando apenas os valores para espaço em branco).

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema seria utilizando [`expressão regular`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular).

Usando a função [`regexp_like`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) que é específica do dialeto PL-SQL.

Desta forma uma consulta que soluciona o problema seria:

```
SELECT id, nome FROM usuario WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (nome, '^\s')
```

Consultando a documentação podemos ver como construir a expressão regular,  devemos utilizar o elemento âncora <kbd>^</kbd> que representa o inicio da string e utilizamos o caractere coringa que representa o espaço em branco em expressões regulares <kbd>\s</kbd>.

#### Modelo para testes

```
CREATE TABLE usuario (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  nome VARCHAR2(32)
  -- no padrão ANSI usar:
  -- nome VARCHAR(32)
);
  
 
INSERT INTO usuario (id, nome) VALUES (1, ' eu');
INSERT INTO usuario (id, nome) VALUES (2, '  tu');
INSERT INTO usuario (id, nome) VALUES (3, '   ele');
INSERT INTO usuario (id, nome) VALUES (4, ' Nós');
INSERT INTO usuario (id, nome) VALUES (5, 'Vós  ');
INSERT INTO usuario (id, nome) VALUES (6, 'Eles');
INSERT INTO usuario (id, nome) VALUES (7, 'eu também');
INSERT INTO usuario (id, nome) VALUES (8, 'voce  também');
INSERT INTO usuario (id, nome) VALUES (9, 'vossa merce também   ');
```

Resultado da execução da consulta:

| Id | Nome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | eu |
| 2 | tu |
| 3 | ele |
| 4 | Nós |

#### Uma solução que utiliza o padrão SQL (ANSI)

Para implementar uma solução que funciona no padrão SQL basta utilizar a função [`like`](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

Segue um exemplo de como ficaria a consulta:

```
SELECT id, nome FROM usuario WHERE nome LIKE ' %';
```

O caractere coringa do operador `like` é o <kbd>%</kbd>.

Repare que essas funções não são equivalentes, visto que utilizando o operador `like` estamos considerando só o caractere espaço em branco (U+0020). Enquanto no código que utiliza a expressão regular (`\s`) está contido mais alguns caracteres, listados abaixo conforme a [`documentação`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm#1006817).

A expresão regular `\s` faz o casamento de padrão equivalente à `[ \f\n\r\t\v]`.

| Simbolo | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| `\f` | avanço de página |
| `\n` | quebra de linha |
| `\r` | carriage return |
|  | espaço em branco |
| `\t` | tab |
| `\v` | tab vertical |